# How to default the date time other than today in SSRS

Tags: sql, datetime, ssrs-2012

I have a parameter `@enddate` to get the date value. Currently we have default value as `Now()`.

It works fine with a today date and current time.

When I pick another day for this `enddate`, it shows as the d but the time never changes.

Can I default the time as `11:59:59pm` when select days other than today but still get the current time when select today?

Thank you

Comment: Do you really need the time? There's no difference between `WHERE DateTimeField < @DATETIME` and `WHERE CAST(DateTimeField AS DATE) < @DATE` for NOW().

Answer (score 0):

You can make some changes to your query and parameter set up and you will be able to accomplish what you asked, "default the time as 11:59:59pm when select days other than today but still get the current time when select today".

Add another parameter after your `@enddate` and I will call it `@enddate2`. Set `@enddate2` to be a datetime field, set it to hidden, and replace all existing `@enddate` in your queries with `@enddate2`.

Use the below code for your `@enddate2` default value. The code basically says if your `@enddate` is the current day, then it will display same value as what you had (today with current time). Otherwise, it will use the date from `@enddate` and add `11:59:59pm` to the time.

```
=IIF(
Format(Parameters!enddate.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy")=Format(NOW(), "MM/dd/yyyy"),
NOW(),
DATEADD("h", 23, DATEADD("n", 59, DATEADD("s", 59, Format(Parameters!enddate.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy")))))
```

Comment: Hi Papermoon 88, thank you for the answer.  the method works fine at the beginning but an error then comes out without any further change.  The error is The defaultValue expression for the report parameter 'enddate2' contains an error: Argument 'DateValue' cannot be converted to type 'Date'. (rsRuntimrErroeInExpression )

Comment: Hi Papermoon88. I just changed enddate=Today() and enddate2==IIF(
Format(Parameters!enddate.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy")=Format(Today(), "MM/dd/yyyy"),
NOW(),
DATEADD("h", 23, DATEADD("n", 59, DATEADD("s", 59, Format(Parameters!enddate.Value)))))       ---------- this works perfectly.